# Admob & Cocos2d - admob not able to be tapped - View not in hierarchy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I am having an issue whereby the Admob banner shows, however, when you tap it, it either crashes the app, or does nothing.

It is using admob mediation, split with iAd, if an iAd displays, it can be tapped no problem...

```
- (void) onEnter {

    if (![MKStoreManager featureAPurchased])
    {

        controller = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        CGFloat screenXPos = (screenWidth /2);
        CGFloat screenYPos = screenHeight - 25;
        [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
        bannerView_.rootViewController = controller;
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        bannerView_.rootViewController = controller;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] addSubview: bannerView_];
        [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];


    }else{

        bannerView_.hidden = YES;
    }
```

The error is if I try to tap a banner nothing happens, and in the console I see the following error;

```
Attempt to present <GADBrowserController: 0x1d576ca0> on <RootViewController: 0x1e8ed3f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Would appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

do not add the banner view to CCDirector's EAGLView, add it to app's RootViewController

Do something like :

```
 AppDelegate * delegate =[[UiApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 [delegate.viewController addSubview: bannerView_];
 [delegate bringSubViewToFront:bannerView_]
```

doing that you don't need the 'controller' at all

So you're basically adding the ad on the same level as the EAGLView is..so when you present the ad (when tapped on it) you just show it over the glView

**edit:**

```
 - (void) onEnter {
   if (![MKStoreManager featureAPurchased])
   {
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat screenXPos = (screenWidth /2);
    CGFloat screenYPos = screenHeight - 25;
    [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
    AppDelegate * delegate =[[UiApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [delegate.rootViewController addSubview: bannerView_];
    [delegate bringSubViewToFront:bannerView_]
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}else{
    bannerView_.hidden = YES;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Skytz, whereabouts would I put that code? Would I need to declare any variables anywhere else?

Comment: Can anyone else help with this?

Comment: @user1695971 just copy and paste the function i wrote in my edited answer instead of yours

Comment: Hi Skytz, it gives me an error unidentified identifier 'delegate' I know that i'll need to define it in the .h file, but I cannot think what I would do that?

With RootViewController I had this in the .h file;

RootViewController *controller;

What could I use for the delegate you posted above?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: You don't need to define anything in your interface, just import the AppDelegate.h where you want to use it and that's all. Doesn't your delegate have a viewController as property? just add the banner view to that. And i use app delegate instead of root view controller because you can have multiple controllers ..but only one delegate (except of some special cases)..and that delegate must always have a root view controller..so it's a pretty safe bet the banner will be attached to something even if you change the app in the future